# Is it possible to skip to another Tier?

Tags: league-of-legends

Since season 4 has started, you no longer have a reduced LP gain in divisions 1 (Gold I) for example. In s3 you gained 5-10 lp with a normal mmr and now you gain 18-24.

Now since it's possible to skip divisions inside of a tier (Gold 4 -> Gold 2) if your mmr is high enough, is it actually possible to skip a division 1?

I got placed in gold 2 after my placement matches but my mmr is far higher. My last game was + 35 LP so would it be possible for me to jump from gold 2 to platinum 5 if i win my promotion? or would i just gain even more LP in division 1, or would i have to wait untill platinum to skip a division?

Comment: I dont think it is possible, don't have a source though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no cases of a player going directly from tier 2 to a divisional promotion. The divisional series are meant to be more difficult to reach and surpass, and therefore tend to be something of a "hard stop" when it comes to advancing.

Be careful about making assumptions about your MMR at this stage of the season. A system like the LoL matchmaking algorithm is designed to have high variance while the sample size remains small, allowing for greater movement within the ladder until the larger performance trends become more apparent. Your +35 LP could indicate that the algorithm expects you to advance, but it does not necessarily mean that you are underrated by a margin so far outside the normal bounds as to warrant skipping a division. Particularly now, after just finishing your placements, it would seem more likely that the algorithm would simply place you in Gold I instead of putting you in a position where skipping a division would be inevitable.

I hope I'm not raining on your parade too hard. Climbing the ladder should be fun on its own without counting on division skips. Best of luck in the new season.